# Show/Hide Div (a long list) on Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are many solutions to show/hide on select in stackoverflow, and almost all of them help when the number of select and divs are small finite number. I am looking for a solution when the select list is really long, maybe over 40 and there are equivalent number of divs.
Is there a generic way to enable show/hide in this situation.? However, If there are SO posts on this, please point them to me.

Here is my HTML structure...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="changeType">Type of Change</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="changeTypeSelect" name="changeTypeSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--- SELECT ---</option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
      ..
      ...LOT MORE HERE...
      .....

      <option value="2">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="1" class="changeTypeDiv">
<hr>
<h1>ONE</h1>
</div>

<div id="2" class="changeTypeDiv">
<hr>
<h1>TWO</h1>
</div>

...
....LOT MORE HERE.....
...

<div id="3" class="changeTypeDiv">
<hr>
<h1>TWO</h1>
</div>
```

I need to be able to show a DIV on select and hide the rest.

### UPDATE to question

If I had more than one select option boxes, do I need to replicate the script or write new function...here is what I tried to do, but it does not work.
DISCLAIMER - It might be evident that I don;t have much insight into coding :)

```
$(function() {
            $(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
            $("#changeTypeSelect").change(function(){
                $(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
                $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
            });

            $(".addGUIdiv").hide();
            $("#addedGUIselect").change(function(){
              $(".addGUIdiv").hide();
              $)"#"+$(this).val()).show();  
            });
        });
```

The above does not work..making me guess, I might need a new function..please help.

Thanks
Brijesh.

Comment: is there any relation between select and div?

Comment: Can you please clarify, what do you mean by relation? The divs after the select should appear when corresponding select option is selection.

Comment: IDs must be unique, and you need to create a relation between selected value and div. then use that relation

Comment: If i select the first option, which div has to show?

Comment: Thanks satpal, I will fix that. But my real question is about a generic solution to show/hide div based on the select option.

Comment: Give the select a value and match that to an id or index of the div

Comment: Any help on the udpated query please....I have more than one list and list has corresponding set of div to show and hide. how do I add that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a relation between selected value and div.

*as per your comment*, Since you have defined the relation. `ID`of div is same as `value` of select.

you can use it like

*HTML*

```
<select id="changeTypeSelect" name="changeTypeSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--- SELECT ---</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<div id="1" class="changeTypeDiv">
    <h1>ONE</h1>
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
$("#changeTypeSelect").change(function(){
    $(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
    $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/51925hkr/)

Comment: HI Satpal, could you help with the updated question ...thanks in advance.

Comment: I have 3 to 4 divs, and each Div has 2 select lists.

Comment: @bbh, https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/o71mxvzu/ might this help you, Here I have use class selector. Notice class of select

Comment: apologies, the html construct was wrong, I have updated it properly. The thing is, the second list and its div's are inside a div and will appear only when the main div is visible. https://jsfiddle.net/o71mxvzu/2/

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this,

```
$(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
$("#changeTypeSelect").change(function() {
    $(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
    $(".changeTypeDiv").eq($(this).val() - 1).show();
});
```

Here I am taking the index based selection..

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/79xbw2uq/5/)

Other Possible solution is to give a `data-attribute` to the div elements. Then show the proper div accordindg to the selection.

Comment: Anoope, all the DIv as visible when you open the page, they div should be visible only select.....

Comment: @bbh are you from kerala?

Comment: Yup, I am. How are you?

Comment: fine, where is your proper place?

Comment: Hey, Anoop, I am from PGT, but I don't the rules of stackoverflow, so  not sure if we are allowed to discuss off-topic items here...

Answer (score 1):

Hide all of them then show the one with `id = value` of select event.

```
$(".changeTypeDiv").hide(); // Hide all
$("#changeTypeSelect").change(function(){
    $(".changeTypeDiv").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```